# Flex data binding to a [Bindable] property of a variable (unable to detect warning)

Tags: apache-flex, binding

I have the following code:

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import shared.GlobalsManager;
    import app.Globals;
    protected var globals:Globals=GlobalsManager.getGlobals();
]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:FormItem label="Server or Client:">
<s:DropDownList id="serverOrClient" dataProvider="{globals.serverOrClientOptions}" />
</s:FormItem>
```

And the relevant Globals class code (Globals extends from GlobalsAdminGlobalS)

```
public class GlobalsAdminGlobalS extends GlobalsAdminS {
    public static const ServerOrClient_server:String="server";
    public static const ServerOrClient_client:String="client";
    public static const ServerOrClient_both:String="both";
    [Bindable]
    public var serverOrClientOptions:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection(
        [ServerOrClient_server,ServerOrClient_client,ServerOrClient_both]);
    [Bindable]
    public var appOrAdminOptions:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection(
        [AppOrAdmin_App,AppOrAdmin_Admin]);
}
```

I am getting the following warning with the Flex 4.5.1 compiler:

```
WARNING S:\_flash\shared\shared\src\shared\admin\global\ClassManager.mxml[28]:
Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "globals".

<s:DropDownList id="serverOrClient" dataProvider="{globals.serverOrClientOptions}" />
```

I have not tested if it actually binds. I dont see what the problem is. According to this and what the expected functionality is, one does not need to mark an entire class bindable:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/databinding_pitfalls.html

EDIT: The Script block is located in a parent of the of the FormItem. The global variable is marked as protected.

1) Can children of a component access properties defined in the component's script blocks?

2) If the functionality of properties defined in an ancestor's script blocks, is the same as properties of a class instance (ie they are not magically available in the curly braces of child components), does a descendant generally access the ancestor or any another component instance through its id property?

Comment: Thank you it has been answered by Sunil D. The questions at the bottom are not relevant to the issue but are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the warning, you need to make the protected `globals` variable bindable in your first code snippet:

```
[Bindable]
protected var globals:Globals=GlobalsManager.getGlobals();
```

Yes, you do not need to make the entire GlobalsManager class bindable. But, in your first code snippet, you are using the `globals` variable inside of a curly brace expression (in the assignment for the dataProvider).

Any variable used inside of a curly brace expression must be bindable...

[Edit]
Note, if a variable or property used in a curly brace expression is NOT bindable, the curly brace expression gets evaluated once and only once. When the vars/props in the curly brace epxression are bindable, they get evaluated each time the var/property changes.

[Additional Answers]

> 1) Can children of a component access properties defined in the
>   component's script blocks?

If you declare variable as `public` in the script block, yes, it will be accessible.

> 2) If the functionality of properties defined in an ancestor's script
>   blocks, is the same as properties of a class instance (ie they are not
>   magically available in the curly braces of child components), does a
>   descendant generally access the ancestor or any another component
>   instance through its id property?

Yes, the id property in mxml is a variable name that you can refer to the object in Actionscript statements.